# java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo

Tags: react-native

When I run the command `yarn start`, the project to launch the development server build. I get no error, but in the logcat in Android Studio, I get the following error and I can't find the source of the problem.

```json
"react-native": "0.67.5",
"react-native-device-info": "^10.10.0",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arq3T.png)

```
Unhandled SoftException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:66)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoModule.invalidate(DeviceInfoModule.java:114)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:110)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:108)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:368)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
```

I'm expecting the home page of my app to be displayed, but I get a blank page, nothing is displayed.